# How to fix ClassCastException: in javax.ws.rs-api RuntimeDelegate.class

Tags: java, casting, runtime-error

My service works during unit testing but getting runtime errors. There is a main connector and then there are plugins within the framework.

```
    ClassCastException: attempting to cast jar: file:/dir/
    /connector-g935ea6c/service/lib/javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.jar!
    /javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.class

    to 

    jar:file:/dir/services/var/data/plugins/install/new-connector-6/asset-plugin.jar!/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.class
```

Is there a way I could make sure the cast is fine? Can I make sure they are both the same version?

I unzipped the asset-plugin.jar and looked at the following: 
META-INF/maven/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api/pom.properties

```
version=2.1
groupId=javax.ws.rs
artifactId=javax.ws.rs-api
```

Comment: They're being loaded from different jars, which as far as Java is concerned means they're different classes. You have to ensure that both sides of the container are using the same exact one.

Comment: how can I do that? 1 is a service and the other one is a plugin? can I lock the versions?

Comment: I don't know the details of how to manage that; problems like this are one of the reasons I'm an enthusiastic user of embedded-server platforms like Spring Boot and Micronaut.